# Javascript Dojo/Dijit Radio Button On-Click Event Won't Fire if Same Button Clicked again

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I can create Dijit radio buttons with on-click event and they work fine. However, when the same button - i.e. the button that is currently checked - is clicked again, the on-click event does not fire. How can I make it so that there is an event callback I can use when the currently checked radio button is clicked again?

I am using dijit/form/RadioButton".

I create the radio button pro grammatically as follows:

```
var aRadioButton = new RadioButton({
  checked: someBooleanValue,
  value: someValue,
  name: someName,
  onClick: lang.hitch(this, buttonCallback) // This works, except for when same button is clicked.
});
```

Comment: You can't change this behaviour without overriding `_onClick` [method](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/form/_RadioButtonMixin.js#L58), because it's designed to suppress `onClick` event when radio is checked or disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo does not support this behavior for a `RadioButton` by default.

In alternative to a monkey path of function `_onClick` in file `_RadioButtonMixin.js` you could instead add directly an event listener on the dom itself, in this example I use `focusNode` on `RadioButton`.

Live example:

https://jsfiddle.net/gibbok/kwdy5gqc/

```
  require([
  "dojo/on",
  "dojo/parser",
  "dijit/form/RadioButton",
  "dijit/form/Button", // used for example purpose
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(on, parser, RadioButton) {
  var radioOne = new RadioButton({
    checked: true,
    value: "tea",
    name: "drink"
  }, "radioOne");

  var radioTwo = new RadioButton({
    checked: false,
    value: "coffee",
    name: "drink"
  }, "radioTwo");

  var signal = on(radioOne.focusNode, "click", function(event) {
    // this code will fire when domNode is clicked
    alert('click on input tea');
  });

  var signal = on(radioTwo.focusNode, "click", function(event) {
    // this code will fire when domNode is clicked
    alert('click on input cafee');
  });


  parser.parse();
});
```

---

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="radio" name="drink" id="radioOne" checked value="tea" />
  <label for="radioOne">Tea</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="drink" id="radioTwo" value="coffee" />
  <label for="radioTwo">Coffee</label>
  <br />

  <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button">
    Show form submit value
    <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="click">
      require(["dojo/dom"], function(dom){ with(dom.byId('myform'))with(elements[0])with(elements[checked?0:1])alert(name+'='+value); return false; });
    </script>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried this alternal solution with assigning event to `domNode`? I can't see difference - event remains suppressed when radio is checked.

Comment: @barbsan thanks for your comment, please have a look to my edit :)

Comment: Right, now it works. Instead of long `radioOne.domNode.childNodes[0]` you can use also `radioOne.focusNode` :)